# HTML - consistent file paths

Tags: html, file, path

When I open a .html file locally, I refer to files like so:

```
'images/background.jpg'
```

But when I put the files on my website, now I need to refer to it as:

```
'/images/background.jpg'
```

Is there any way I can write it so that it will be correct in both situations?

Comment: Depends on your server configuration/website url. The first line is a relative path relative to the current page url. The second line is relative to your hostname/domain.

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad not sure I understand. Should I assume that because it doesn't work, there's no way?

Comment: If you could paste in the complete URL showing in your browser for both the local HTML file and the complete URL when it's uploaded to your website it would help.

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad uh, sure:
Local HTML file: file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Dropbox/HTML/PF/index.html
Website: adam.comze.com (or adam.comze.com/index.html)
I'm not sure what you expected, but there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're developing web sites on you local machine you should try to replicate the server environment as much as possible. Run a local web server on your machine. Testing web pages via the `file://` "protocol" is a bad idea. Chrome won't even allow you to load scripts and stuff this way.

[mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) is a small and simple web server you could use.

This is the best way to structure your URL's, this means they're relative to the root of your domain. `images` folder is located in the root folder:

```
'/images/background.jpg'
```

By using `mongoose` or similar on your local machine it will work the same way as on the server.

You could of course install a full WAMP/LAMP/XAMP stack on your computer, but `mongoose` is a simple alternative. If you use `PHP` on your site you could also use the dev server available in the `php` command via the `-S` switch.